# Start only one service in a docker-compose.yml with ansible docker_service module

Tags: docker, ansible, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose.yml file like this

```
version: '2' 
    services:
        my-service-one:
        // parameters of my-service-one
        my-service-two:
            extends: my-service-one
            //extra params for my-service-two
        my-service-three
            extends: my-service-one
            //extra params for my-service-three
```

And I want to start only one of the services, like my-service-three,  using ansible [docker_service module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/docker_service_module.html)

I believe it will be something like:

```
docker_service:
    project_src: /path/to/dir/containing/docker-compose.yml
    some-parameter: my-service-three
```

What would be the parameter(s) to set in the docker_service module to run only one service ?

Comment: What have you done to verify your beliefs (except for posting on SO)? What was the result?

Comment: @techraf I looked the docker_service documentation but didn't note the 'services' parameter mentioned in the accepted answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The document does mention the `services` parameter but not in an obvious way.

> When state is present run docker-compose up on a subset of services.

```
docker_service:
  project_src: /path/to/dir/containing/docker-compose.yml
  services:
    - my_service
  state: present
```

Comment: would be good to have one example with this scenario in the doc of docker_service